# Setting a variable when a stubbed method is called in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

In one of my tests I want to perform a `before :all` action, and need to want to also test that a method is not called in this `before :all` action. Is there a way to do this?

e.g. I want to be able to:

```
before :all do
  @bar_called = false
  # set @bar_called to true if bar is called on an instance of class Foo
  do_other_stuff
end
```

and then, in one of my specs later on, expect that `@bar_called == false`

Answer (score 0):

You could also implement your mock with a block, then set `@bar_called`.

`expect(obj).to receive(:my_method) { @bar_called = true }`

Now, you may want to consider setting the expectation on the mock/stub instead

`expect(obj).to receive(:my_method).exactly(0).times`

See the [RSpec-Mocks documentation on receive counts](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/setting-constraints/receive-counts).